# Add Login View before Tabbar Content ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have the following requirements:

A Tabbar Navigation, with 2 "Tabs" that include a Login. So if a user tab (for example) an Button3 of the UITabBar ill get a fullscreen login view - But only on 2 specific tabs.

This is the workflow:

[image]

If there is an active session (i am using a login session management) - i will not present a login button - but if there is none, a login window should appear in fullscreen.

So when ill now show in any of the RootViewControllers in ViewDidLoad the loginViewController, the "content" of the rootViewControllers still get loaded.

So ill my opinion ill should handle after click on a button, WITHOUT loading the RootViewController for that tab.

Can anyone help me whats the best approach to solve such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -(BOOL)tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController: method of UITabBarDelegate to handle tab selection and present login view instead of activating tab if needed.

You'll possible need to store a callback (i. e. block), in which you activate tab manually using tabBar.selectedIndex = index.

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSInteger index = [_tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    if (index==4)
    {
        if (_authorized)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            [self authorize];
            __weak UITabBarController *tabBarController = _tabBarController;
            _authorizationCallback = ^(){
                //
                tabBarController.selectedIndex = 4;
            };
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, that what i am looking for. So i could store the "last" tab if the login failures (or the user will not login). Thanks!